# Question about Units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Find a nonzero element in a ring that is neither a zero-divisor nor a unit.

Would $\mathbb Z_7$ work for this example? I know it has no zero divisors, but I am confused about the unit portion.

Can someone help?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_7$ is a field, so everything's a unit.

Comment: :Every non zero element  of $\mathbb Z_n$ is a unit or a zero divisor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No finite ring will work because if a finite (commutative, all rings to me are commutative and with unity) ring has no zero divisors, then it has to be a field. So we need an infinite ring, my favorite is $\Bbb Z$. My favorite integer is $21$, and $21$ is not a zero divisor or a unit in $\Bbb Z$, since $\Bbb Z$ has no zero divisors and only $\pm 1$ are units.

Comment: I prefer $3256623236$ myself.

Comment: Yes, no finite ring will work, but the reason *because finite domains are fields* does not fit the original question well. A better reason would be *because in finite rings elements are either units or zero divisors.* (True even in noncommutative rings.)

Comment: One more good thing to mention is that infinite cardinality is necessary but it's not sufficient. All artinian rings, finite or otherwise, have only units and zero divisors and nothing else.

Comment: @tomasz May I know why do you prefer only this number as a unit? I am just interested to know!

Comment: @USER0117: Sorry, it's been a while, I don't really remember. It was probably random. It's not a unit, though. The point of the question was to find an element which is *not* a unit (and not a zero divisor).